# express authentication middleware failing to redirect correctly after a PUT request

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

I'm using passportjs with a middleware below. It is suppose to check if the user is login when he requests certain things. If he is not signed in, he should be redirected to the login page.

I have a request route as follows:

```
app.put('/fantasyteams/:fantasyTeamId', auth.requiresLogin, fantasyteams.update);
```

This route will be called when the user tries to update a resource called Fantasy Team in the website

auth.requiresLogin is a middleware as follows:

```
exports.requiresLogin = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()

  }
  return res.redirect("/signin");
};
```

After logging in my user, I simulated session expiry by deleting the session cookie. Thereafter thru the website I made a PUT '/fantasyteams/123' request to update fantasy team number 123.

fantasyteams.update is simply a mongodb / mongoose save operation:

```
exports.update = function(req, res){
    var fantasyteam = req.fantasyteam;
    fantasyteam = _.extend(fantasyteam, req.body);
    fantasyteam.save(function(err){
        res.jsonp(fantasyteam);
    });
};
```

As expected, the route handler (app.put ... ) above caught the request, pass it to the auth.requiresLogin middleware to check if the user is logged in. So it turns out the user isn't logged in since I deleted his session cookie. res.redirect is called as expected. However, the website doesn't redirect to the sign in page. I see this in the node.js command logs:

```
PUT /signin 404 328ms
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: this redirecting is taking place in my middleware, so the answer you supplied does not apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is you don't have a route handler for PUT /signin. The original request was a put, so when it redirects it's still part of that same 'put' request from the browser. Just add a handler for put/post/whatever with app.all('/signin')

Comment: is there a way to change the response method to a GET? from the PUT request to a GET /signin?

Comment: Oh yes it doesn't work by the way. Right now i'm getting an internal server error. The middleware seems to be passing on to the next middleware instead of redirecting the browser /signin

Comment: The method, GET/PUT/POST/etc comes from the browser, i.e. the browser says "I want to PUT to "/fantasyteams/:fantasyTeamId" so it doesn't make much sense to be able to change that request from the browser to a GET. The only thing you can do is send back a response to that request. Please post more code.